# I want to show relational data, when theres data missing in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show relational data, when theres data missing  in a mysql query , I have the following query

```
SELECT u.user_email, um1.value AS school, um.value AS postcode
FROM `wp_users` AS u, `wp_bp_xprofile_data` AS um, `wp_bp_xprofile_data` AS um1
WHERE u.ID = um.user_id
AND u.ID = um1.user_id
AND um.field_id =322
AND um1.field_id =69
```

This brings out an email address, the name of a school and a postcode. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get all the emails if either school or postcode are not in the database i.e. show values even if data is missing

Cheers,
Rich

Comment: I trust you are aware [the relational model does not include nulls](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Missing-info-without-nulls.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_email 
,       um1.value AS school
,       um.value AS postcode
FROM `wp_users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `wp_bp_xprofile_data` AS um
  ON u.ID = um.user_id
  AND um.field_id = 322
LEFT JOIN `wp_bp_xprofile_data` AS um1
  ON u.ID = um1.user_id
  AND um1.field_id = 69
```